# Variable Scope of Closure PHP|Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone help me understand the variable scope for this scenario? I have a variable `$i` and I am accessing this variable in closure then increasing it. But, when I print variable `$i` outside the closure it prints `0`(the initial value). How can I make sure the effects in the variable `$i` is accessible from outside?

```php
class ImportsController{

    public function sync()
    {
        $i = 0;

        LazyCollection::make(function () use (&$csv_data) {
            $datas = $csv_data;
            foreach ($datas as $line) {
                if (count($line) == $key_count && !containsOnlyNull($line)) {
                    yield $line;
                }
            }
        })
        ->chunk(50)
        ->each(function ($lines) use (&$i) {
            foreach ($lines as $chunk) {
                if ($lines) {
                    $i++;
                }
           }
        });

        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use a protect variable in your Class `private $i;` you can then use `$this->i` which would be accessible within your function

Comment: it's worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a private variable on your class for this purpose:

```
class ImportsController{

private $i;

    public function sync()
    {
        $this->i = 0;

        LazyCollection:: 
        ...
        ->each(function ($lines) {
            foreach ($lines as $chunk) {
                if ($lines) 
                    $this->i++;
           }
        });

        echo $this->i;
    }
}
```